# Do optical flow methods work for analyzing object growth or moving interfaces?

Tags: python, opticalflow

I'm new to coding and I'm trying to use use python to calculate the velocity of a moving/growing interface to analyze some of my data for a research project.

So far, I have seen that optical flow techniques are used for tracking vehicles, but I'm wondering if there is a better method for looking at growth or interfaces?

> For a very simplified example,  if I have a colored rectangle in frame
>   1 ([image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9YFZ.jpg)) that increases in size over the course of a video to
>   frame n ([image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ6WK.jpg)), would optical flow techniques apply to
>   calculate the velocity of growth in this case? Or is there another
>   algorithm I should be considering?

Thanks!
Reference Images:

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9YFZ.jpg)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJ6WK.jpg)